# How to display array length in Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, debugging

When debugging a java program in Eclipse, I can see (e.g. in the *Variables view*) the content of an arbitrary array, see the picture bellow (with the `ByteArrayInputStream.buf` field).

[image: Eclipse Variables view with an array]

But I cannot find the **array length** field anywhere. Is there a way to show the length of an array in Eclipse debugger? How can I do it?

Comment: The latest array segment (e.g [500..599]) holds the length.

Comment: you can also check the length from Expression Tab just add `array.length ` or `array.size()` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Expressions" view and evaluate the `length` member:

[image: Expression tab screenshot]

Keep in mind that the last index is one less than the length!

While this works for **public** array members, it seems that an explicit cast is required for protected members. Consider the following code:

```
...
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[1769]);
...
```

Now, when evaluating `is.buf`, the Expressions view shows a dump of the array as shown in the question, but evaluating `is.buf.length` fails with `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>`. If we add an explicit cast to `ByteArrayInputStream`, the evaluation works:

[image]

Comment: But it does not work for **private** or **protected** fields like in my case: `is.buf.length`. Eclipse prints: `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation> buf cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: Aha the problem was actually wrong type (`InputStream`). This woks just fine: `((ByteArrayInputStream) is).buf.length`

Comment: Good observation! Not sure why the Expression evaluator requires an explicit cast here (since it already knows that `buf` is an array), but I can exactly reproduce what you say...

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for your answer (comment). You are right, the latest array segment (in my case: [1700..1768]) holds the length.

The whole picture:

[image: the whole picture]